# How to setup Spring-Boot AbstractRoutingDatasource so transactions and hibernate works properly with Spring-Data?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I need your help in setting up AbstractRoutingDatasource for multiple DBs in Spring-Boot so Transactions and Hibernate works properly.
I read multiple blogs about it:

1. https://fable.sh/blog/splitting-read-and-write-operations-in-spring-boot/
2. http://fedulov.website/2015/10/14/dynamic-datasource-routing-with-spring/
3. https://kimrudolph.de/blog/spring-datasource-routing

and 1. looks promising but it doesn't contain

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { 
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
```

like in 3 (https://github.com/krudolph/spring-datasource-routing/blob/master/src/main/java/de/kimrudolph/routing/RoutingApplication.java

https://github.com/krudolph/spring-datasource-routing/blob/master/src/main/java/de/kimrudolph/routing/DataSourceConfiguration.java).

So my question is what is the right way to configure AbstractRoutingDatasource? Can I just configure the datasources like in 1. (here is the source code: https://github.com/DominicGunn/fable-spring-read-replica/blob/master/src/main/java/sh/fable/persistence/DataSourceConfig.java) and Spring-Boot will configure transactionmanager and hibernate automatically in a right manner or do I have to configure everything manually like in 3.?

The desired behaviour should be:

- I choose in my code DB1 and start a transaction and this transaction should work in isolation (only on DB1)
- later I choose in my code DB2 and start a transaction and this transaction should work in isolation (only on DB2)
- there should be no sharing of objects/caches in Hibernate/JPA between transactions on DB1 and transactions on DB2
- it should work with Spring-Data

Comment: What have you tried... Hint, I suggest to start with 1, another hint Spring Boot will not auto configure a bean if it already finds a bean of that type (in general) so if you define your datasource, it will not create one. Everything else will be created for you (that is the whole point of Spring Boot).

Comment: 1. should work and transactionmanager+hibernate should be created by Spring-Boot but how will the default transactionmanager-configuration and hibernate-configuration work with different datasources? Can they just work with multiple datasources without problems or should a different transactionmanager-configuration and hibernate-configuration be created per new datasource?

Comment: There is only 1 DataSource, the routing one. That underneath it are multiple doesn’t matter. Hence my initial comment of what have you tried...

Comment: So then 1. should work without problems. Thanks